# Cколько раз слово встречается в строке

Tags: javascript

Нужно узнать количество вхождений этого слова в строке.

Пример строки

```
'type, status, date, status'
```

Ищем вхождение слова

```
status
```

Comment: Что вы уже пробовали, и как искали решение? Посмотрите на метод строки `.match(/ваше_слово/)` – что он возвращает. И на свойство массива `.length`.

Comment: "одно слово или два слова плюс словосочетание" - сколько раз здесь встречается слово "слово"? По хорошему - два ("слово" и "слова" - разное написание, но слово одно и то же), по плохому - тоже два ("**слово**" и "**слово**сочетание"), а вам надо показать что здесь только одно такое слово? @Sergiks, там границу слова надо указывать, чтобы точно определялось, но для русских букв вроде это не работает (либо я не знаю как заставить работать)

Comment: Если сложно с регулярными выражениями, воспользуйтесь методом indexOf().

Comment: @BOPOH надо, чтобы ТС уточнил задачу и свой уровень. «"слово" и "слова" - разное написание, но слово одно и то же» – *корень* один и тот же, *слова* разные. А то давайте сюда ещё словарь синонимов привяжем)

Comment: @AlexeyKopantsev, `indexOf` тоже не корректно отработает, если слово будет являться частью другого слова (например, "реле" и "перелезание"). Рабочий вариант "в лоб" - через `.match(/[\wа-яА-ЯёЁ]+/g)` разбиваем строку на слова и сравниваем каждое слово в отдельности

Comment: согласен. НО, каков вопрос - таков ответ, да и к тому же, у массивов indexOf() то же есть. А если слово вводится пользователем? какую регулярку вы будете использовать?

Comment: @AlexeyKopantsev идеальный вопрос содержал бы набор тестов )

Comment: так регулярка та же самая, разбили - получили массив слов, а дальше уже сравниваем с тем, что ввел пользователь. Проблем не вижу, либо не понял что имеется ввиду

Comment: Сколько вхождений слово `папа` в строке `папапапа папарацци папа ПаПА моему папе 40 лет`? 7? 6? 5? 3? 2? 1? Очень надо уточнить вопрос.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вариант "в лоб" с помощью indexOf:

```
function countWord(source, word) {
    if(!word)
        return 0;
    var res = 0, index = 0;
    while((index = source.indexOf(word)) >= 0) {
        source = source.substring(index + word.length);  
        res++;
    }
    return res;
}
```

Comment: `countWord("одно слово или два слова плюс словосочетание", "слово")` равно 2, а ТС скорее всего надо 1

Comment: @BOPOH тут сложно сказать что-то более конкретно - было бы неплохо, если бы ТС потрудился описать вопрос более детально. Если именно с учетом словоформ, и/или без учета однокоренных слов, то это как минимум надо отдельно оговаривать